# C# - JSON serialization for SNS

Tags: c#, json, amazon-sns

I want to serialize a message to be sent through AWS SNS module.

```
public async Task<string> jsonConvert(string message)  
{
    datamessage datamessage = new datamessage { message = message };
    gcmMessage lGcm = new gcmMessage { data = datamessage };
    MessageDto messageDto = new MessageDto { GCM = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lGcm) };
    var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageDto);
    return msg;
}
```

I'm using this code for the same but the return value is

```
{"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"TestMsg\"}}"}
```

But I want it as

```
{"default": "TestMsg", "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"TestMsg\" } }"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure for the Json you want tot create should look like this:

**Classes:**

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class GCM
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public string Default { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GCM")]
    public GCM GCM { get; set; }
}
```

**Create the message:**

```
RootObject rootObject = new RootObject
{
    Default = "TestMsg",
    GCM = new GCM { Data = new Data { Message = "TestMsg" } }
};
```

**Serialize:**

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
```

**Result**

```
"{\"default\":\"TestMsg\",\"GCM\":{\"data\":{\"message\":\"TestMsg\"}}}"
```

**In your method it would look like this:**

```
public async Task<string> jsonConvert(string message)
{
    RootObject rootObject = new RootObject
    {
        Default = message,
        GCM = new GCM { Data = new Data { Message = message } }
    };

    var msg = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject));
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Good that you also showed how to use `JsonProperty` attribute instead of naming public properties in lowercase. :)

Comment: why do you start a new thread for serialization? Wouldn't be the thread creation/synchronization not more expensive?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt `Task.Factory.StartNew` does not necessarily creates a new thread.

Comment: Thanks Jim, you saved a lot of my time :)

Comment: @AnandSubramanian I hope you can learn something from it, not only saving you time :-)